# How to cancel or undo a checkout from CVS using eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, jboss, cvs

I checked out the code from CVS repository using jboss developer studio 8.0 (IDE). However, i am not able to run/deploy my application in dev studio 8.0 and was suggested to use jboss dev studio 4.0. Now, i want to start over from scratch on jboss dev studio 4.0. I don't want to use the same workspace that was created using jboss dev studio 8.0. 
**My questions:** 
 - How do I cancel the checkout from jboss dev studio 8.0 ?
 
 - What will happen if i check out the code again using jboss dev studio 4.0 on my system ?

Please advise!Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check out from a repository, you create a local copy on your computer. When you commit the changes you made to the local copy, it updates the copy on the server. If you did not commit any changes you made then you do not need to "cancel the checkout." It also does not matter if you check out the code again as it only creates a local copy on your machine.

Comment: So there is no connection between local copy and a copy in repository or any kind of locks on current copy ? [Here](http://vasc.ri.cmu.edu/old_help/Archiving/Cvs/cvs_tutorial.texinfo.html#SEC3) it says use `release` command to cancel the effect of `checkout`.  But not sure how to achieve this using eclipse.

Comment: The default setting is that checkouts do not lock the file so you should be fine. you can refer [here](http://www.thathost.com/wincvs-howto/cvsdoc/cvs_10.html)

Comment: If all you care about is the state of the repository, that's true.  But `checkout` (or `update`) did affect your working copy!  Besides the obvious sub-directory, it may also have written in the containing directory's `CVS/Entries` or `CVS/Entries.Log`.  If it only wrote to `CVS/Entries.Log`, and the checkout/update you want to undo is the only line in it, you're in luck, and you can simply remove that file.  Otherwise you may need to edit one of those text files.